# Missing text when converting docx to pdf with office-interop

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop, word-automation

I have issue that when converting word DOCX files with word-interop to PDF it happends ocassionally that file does not convert well - some part of text is missing.

In my current situation there is missing one text bubble with two lines of text.

I have created a mini test application that converts test.docx to pdf and I see that problem appears on two machines "Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard" with "Office 2010".

Edit: On "Windows 7 Professional" with "Office 2013" : problem is present on two PC's, and everything works OK on one PC (mine workstation).

I'm looking for some leads where to look for solving this problem.

Edit: Here is a image to show what do I mean by "missing one text bubble with two lines of text". 
Left: original document in word. 
Middle: Interop conversion output. 
Right: manually saved DocX to PDF in Word
[image: Left: original in word. Middle: Interop conversion output. Right: manually saved DocX to PDF in Word]

To see enlarged version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kch8.png

Comment: Does Office 2010 present the document well when you simply open it?

Comment: For docx there is another library from Microsoft (but I forget the name) that is built for automation (Office is not).

Comment: Vadim: Yes Office 2010 presents document well. Also Office 2013 presents document well on PC's where it fails to convert (it fails on 2 PC's with Office 2013)